# What is the best way to make multiple requests to the same server in Dart?

Tags: http, dart

I want to make server HTTP requests to the same server and was wondering if there was an efficient way to do so by keeping a persistent connection open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use the `http` Pub package.

For making multiple requests to the same server, keep a persistent connection open by using `http.Client`. This is better than making multiple single requests. Here is some code that shows how this can be done:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() {
   var url = 'http://httpbin.org';
   var client = new http.Client();
   client.get('${url}/foo')
       .then((response) {
         print(response.body);
         return client.get('${url}/bar');
        })
       .then((response) {
         print(response.body);
       });
       .whenComplete(client.close);
}
```

Be sure to close the client connection when done.